# convert string to int error in c#

Tags: c#, string, integer

Hello I am trying to convert String to Integer.

The code below shows a part from where I am trying to convert my string to integer.

```
if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("PickUp"))
{
    if ( checkpointboolean == false)
    {
        string pickupName = other.ToString(); //other = Pickup4
        //Remove first 6 letters thus remaining with '4'
        string y = pickupName.Substring(6); 
        print(y); // 4 is being printed
        int x = 0;
        int.TryParse(y, out x);
        print (x); // 0 is being printed
```

I also tried the below code and instead of '0' I am getting the following error:

```
if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("PickUp"))
{
    if ( checkpointboolean == false)
    {
        //Get Object name ex: Pickup4
        string pickupName = other.ToString();
        //Remove first 6 letters thus remaining with '4'
        string y = pickupName.Substring(6); 
        print(y);
        int x = int.Parse(y);
```

> FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format
>   System.Int32.Parse (System.String s)

Comment: How certain are you that there are no charaters *after* the 4? Try printing `y.Length`...

Comment: you have to debug it step by step with breakpoints

Comment: This seems to tell you that your string contains invalid characters. Are you sure that you have only a 4 in that substring? If you have a debugger try to look at that value, Missing it then change use a print("[" + y + "]"); to see if there are other characters

Comment: Works for me [http://ideone.com/Wc26y6]. I'm with @Steve on this one.

Comment: Try trimming y in case there's extra spacing. ` int.TryParse(y.Trim(), out x);`

Comment: @Peter4499: `Trim()` is of no use in the context, since default NumberStyles.Integer == **NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite** | **NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite** | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign; see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

`int.TryParse` returns a boolean, true if it succeeded and false if not. You need to wrap this in a if block and do something with that logic.

```
if(int.TryParse(y, out x))
    print (x); // y was able to be converted to an int
else
    // inform the caller that y was not numeric, your conversion to number failed
```

As far as why your number is not converted I could not say until you post what the string value is.

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt is the best for this case, that code works fine, The [`int.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) *giving `0` to the out parameter and returns false* means the conversion is failed. The input string is not in the correct format/ it cannot be converted to an integer. You can check this by using the return value of the  `int.TryParse()`. For this what you need to do is :-

```
 if(int.TryParse(y, out x))
     print (x); // 
 else
     print ("Invalid input - Conversion failed");
```

Comment: "The int.TryParse() giving output as 0 means the conversion is failed. " - actually it means it _may_ have failed. It could also just be a string containing 0. OP should properly check the return code.

Comment: @CompuChip: Well, but not " a string containing 0", it will be `0` if the input is `"0"`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `ToString()` usually uses for *debug purpose* so there's no guarantee that

```
 other.ToString()
```

will return the expected `"Pickup4"` in the next version of the software. You, probably, want something like

```
  int x = other.gameObject.SomeProperty;
  int x = other.SomeOtherProperty;
  int x = other.ComputePickUp();
  ...
```

If you, however, insist on `.ToString()` you'd rather not hardcode *six letters* (the reason is the same: *debug information* tends to change from version to version), but use *regular expressions* or something:

```
  var match = Regex.Match(other.ToString(), "-?[0-9]+");

  if (match.Success) {
    int value; 

    if (int.TryParse(match.Value, out value))
      print(value); 
    else
      print(match.Value + " is not an integer value"); 
  }
  else
    print("Unexpected value: " + other.ToString());
```